# Finding nextAll from a specific element on whole page

Tags: jquery, find, reload

Would be awesome if somebody could help me with this problem.

I have a list of elements, which are seperated in different containers, for example:

```
<div id="posts">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="post"></div>
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I save the position of the last element in a variable

```
var lastPost = $("#posts").find(".post").last();
```

Now I load more posts into the dom.

```
...
<div class="container3">
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
</div>
...
```

From the original last position (lastPost) I want to retrieve `nextAll()` posts. Because the divs are not siblings to each other, i cannot access them with `nextAll()`.

It would be awesome if I could get the position of lastPost inside `$("#posts").find(".post")` after adding the posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the posts, the get items after the index of the item referred by `lastPost` like

```
var $all = $('#posts .post');
var $nextAll = $all.slice($all.index(lastPost) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to traverse to parent element and then use `nextAll` to target the sibling parent container.

```
var nextall= lastPost.parent().nextAll().find('.post')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find the closest container and select next all containers and find `.post` inside them

```
var all = lastPost.closest('[id^="container"]').nextAll().find('.post');
```